# how and when to set animationConfig on a paper-dialog

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I have a `paper-dialog` inside of another element looking like:

```
<paper-dialog id="modal" modal>
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <p>Lorem......</p>

  <div class="buttons">
    <paper-button dialog-confirm autofocus>Login</paper-button>
  </div>
</paper-dialog>
```

I could declaratively add `entry-animation` and `exit-animation` but I'm really trying to do two effects at once [like it shows in the docs](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation#using-multiple-animations)

I tried using something like:

```
this.$.modal.animationConfig = {....}; //like the docs
```

and I  set `node` to `this.$.modal`, but I'm pretty certain it doesn't read that variable at all because when I check `this.$.modal.getAnimationConfig('exit')` (or `entry`) I get nothing.

So where in the lifecycle can I do something like this.

The end goal for me is to apply to intertwined (one of them slightly delayed) animations to my `paper-dialog` on `entry` and `exit` like in (as he loves to be called :p ) ["Bob Dod"'s polycast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lwvi1u4XXzc&list=PLOU2XLYxmsII5c3Mgw6fNYCzaWrsM3sMN&index=17)

If you don't know the answer, pointing me in a different direction also helps ;)

Comment: Are you sure about this? I tried setting the animationConfig as `this.$.modal.animationConfig = { ... }` in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7jkLahzt/) and everything worked just fine...

Comment: @Alan I rewrote it and it worked as you said, I'll try to figure out the problem with a git diff or something later to let you know. Thank you so much for the sanity check :)

Comment: @Alan I honestly couldn't figure out why it wasn't working initially. Wanna post your answer and call it a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems my comment was helpful, here it is as an answer:

"Are you sure about this? I tried setting the animationConfig as `this.$.modal.animationConfig = { ... }` in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7jkLahzt/) and everything worked just fine..."

Answer (score 0):

I use polymer with angular 2 and this is the way I try to add animation:

```
if (dialog) {
        dialog.animationConfig = {
            'entry': {
                name: 'transform-animation',
                node: dialog,
                transformFrom: 'translateY(100%)',
                transformTo: 'translateY(0)'
            },
            'exit': {
                name: 'transform-animation',
                node: dialog,
                transformFrom: 'translateY(0)',
                transformTo: 'translateY(100%)'
            }
        };
        dialog.open();
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer.